# ¿Cómo puedo reiniciar el valor de un Sampler2D?

Tags: c++, opengl, material

Estoy trabajando en un programa para cargar modelos 3D utilizando OpenGL. Por el momento, mis shader y código cuentan con soporte para cargar mapas Difuso, Especular y Emisivo.

Tengo entendido que los uniforms están hechos de tal modo que, una vez configurados, estos se quedan con el último valor insertado hasta el próximo cambio, pero es ahí donde empiezan los problemas porque, suponiendo que cargo un modelo con los 3 mapas, y después otro que solo tiene mapas D y S pero no E; el E de este último no es nulo, cero, o lo q sea con lo q se inicialice, sino se queda con el Emisivo del modelo anterior. ¿Hay algún modo de solucionar esto?

Este es el código que utilizo para renderizar mi mesh:

```
void Mesh::Draw(Shader& shader, World::Transform transform, World::Camera camera) {
        {
            // Activate shader and pass transform and camera
            shader.Use();
            shader.setMat4("view", camera.getView());
            shader.setMat4("projection", camera.getProjection());
            shader.setMat4("model", transform.getTransformMatrix());

            // Sampler2D assignation
            unsigned int nDiff = 0;
            unsigned int nSpec = 0;
            unsigned int nNorm = 0;
            unsigned int nHeig = 0;
            unsigned int nEmit = 0;

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < textures.size(); i++) {
                glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i + 1);
                std::string number;
                std::string name = textures[i].type;
                if      (name == "diffuse")  number = std::to_string(nDiff++);
                else if (name == "specular") number = std::to_string(nSpec++);
                else if (name == "normal")   number = std::to_string(nNorm++);
                else if (name == "height")   number = std::to_string(nHeig++);
                else if (name == "emissive") number = std::to_string(nEmit++);

                textures[i].setSampler2D(&shader, ("material." + name + number).c_str(), i + 1);
                textures[i].Bind();
            }

            // Draw call
            vao.Bind();
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
            vao.Unbind();

            // Unbind buffers
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        }
    }
```

Y este es el de setSampler2D, por si acaso:

```
void Texture::setSampler2D(Shader* shader, const char* name, int slot) {
        shader->Use();
        shader->setInt(name, slot);
    }
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es que el uniform se quede "desconfigurado"? Suponiendo que sea así, normalmente el sampler se inicia en el texture unit 0, que también es el texture unit inicial, al que se bindea la textura si no llamas a `glActiveTexture`. Lo que puedes hacer es cambiar el texture unit que está usando a uno sin textura asociada o usar `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)`

Comment: Si, algo así es lo que busco. Por cierto, actualicé la pregunta con el código de mi función Draw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con las siguientes líneas estás restableciendo el texture unit 0 únicamente:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Pero tu código muestra la posibilidad de usar más de un texture unit. Por lo tanto debes restablecerlos todos.

Reemplazando las líneas mencionadas por un for como este debería solucionar tu problema:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < textures.size(); i++) {
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i + 1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Con esto estarías dejando los binding points que usaste tal como los encontraste.

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Ya lo probé y me funcionó. Gracias :D